# after installing gunicorn3 how to fix Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: server, python3

```
root@vps292598:~# sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3.5 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.5.postinst: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.5.postinst: /usr/bin/python3.5: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.5 (>= 3.5.1-2~); however:
  Package python3.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pkg-resources:
 python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pkg-resources (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-setuptools:
 python3-setuptools depends on python3-pkg-resources (= 20.7.0-1); however:
  Package python3-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
 python3-setuptools depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-setuptools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gunicorn:
 python3-gunicorn depends on python3-pkg-resources; however:
  Package python3-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
 python3-gunicorn depends on python3-setuptools; however:
  Package python3-setuptools is not configured yet.
 python3-gunicorn depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gunicorn (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gunicorn3:
 gunicorn3 depends on python3-gunicorn (= 19.4.5-1ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package python3-gunicorn is not configured yet.
 gunicorn3 depends on python3:any (>= 3.2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gunicorn3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-wheel:
 python3-wheel depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-wheel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
 dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.5
 python3
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-setuptools
 python3-gunicorn
 gunicorn3
 python3-wheel
 dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before installing `gunicorn`, it might make sense to ensure Python3 is properly installed and configured:

```
$ sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3 python3.5 python3-minimal python3.5-minimal libpython3.5-minimal
```

If this completes without a problem, *then* you can try to install the `gunicorn` package.

Comment: After executing that command 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libpython3.5-minimal amd64 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12 [524 kB]
Fetched 524 kB in 0s (4,955 kB/s)         
E: Internal Error, No file name for python3.5:amd64

Comment: Add the additional info to the question not as a comment.